# jQuery innerHTML editing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at the code example below

```html
<div id="post-1234">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class"Event-Date">Event Date 1</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="post-4321">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class"Event-Date">Event Date 2</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="post-9999">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class"Event-Date">Event Date 3</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is to have jQuery take the innerHTML of each span class"Event-Date" and append it to the end of the h3 tag above it.

So the end result would be that each h3 would have it's link and then - Event Date 1 2 or 3

Example

```html
<h3><a href="some link">text</a> - Event Date 1</h3>
<h3><a href="some link">text</a> - Event Date 2</h3>
<h3><a href="some link">text</a> - Event Date 3</h3>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve what you want?

Comment: Cant you just output it like that from the start?

Comment: It's a part of a plugin for wordpress.  So I don't want to change the core code of the plugin because any updates to the plugin will break my change.  So i'm just wanting to do it via jquery and modify on the fly

Comment: @WilliamLamoreaux - why use JQuery if you can use WordPress hooks/filters to filter that content of this output with some additional PHP code in your **functions.php** file of the child-theme!? [Here are the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/)

Comment: Thank you richardev.  I've looked into that as well.  But without going into a big explanation......I'd just like to get it done in a simple jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify html like this:

```js
$("div").each(function (){
 if($(this).attr("id") ? ($(this).attr("id").startsWith("post")? true : false):false){
  $(this).find("h3").append(" - "+$(this).find(".Event-Date").text());
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-1234">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class="Event-Date">Event Date 1</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="post-4321">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class="Event-Date">Event Date 2</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="post-9999">
 <h3><a href="some link">text</a></h3>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <span class="Event-Date">Event Date 3</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok great.....Thank you for that so far.  Can you narrow it down to only grab span's that class = "Event-Date"?

Comment: @WilliamLamoreaux your welcome. You forgot to add isequalto sign (`=`) between `class="value"`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the H3 elements you want to modify, then get the spans, and add the span text

```
var h3 = $("h3");
var span = $("span");
for (var i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
  h3.get(i).innerHTML += " : " + span.get(i).innerText;
}
```

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for that code.  It would have to be inside each post-### only though.  There are other H3 and Span's on the page that I don't want to modify.

Comment: @WilliamLamoreaux You can change `$("h3")` to `$("div h3"). Likewise with spans. If that's still catching H3's that it shouldn't, you should add a class like "post" to your post divs and use $("div.post h3");

Comment: Ok thank you for that so far.  Ok so the Span's  I need it to grab the inner html of each span (inside the post-###) where the span class = "Event-Date"

Comment: @WilliamLamoreaux with your spans, innerHTML is the same as innerText. If you need span filtering, you could give your spans classes, or use jQuery.filter and filter out the spans that don't have the text you are searching for